# Empty Histogram: Values Possibly Not Recognized?

Tags: c++, tree, histogram, branch, root-framework

I had a question on how to fix an empty histogram. I am creating a vector called "mass" that I want to plot its histogram (as can be seen in the code) from the variables in my Branches Muon_PT, Muon_Eta, Muon_Phi, and mass. However, I get an empty histogram. I am suspecting that it is not reading the branch variables. I suspect this because when I write something like:

```
auto idx_cmb = Combinations(Muon_PT, 2);
```

I get the error that:

```
Warning in <TROOT::Append>: Replacing existing TH1: mass (Potential memory leak).
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Cannot make unique combinations of size 2 from vector of size 0.
```

Although when I plot the histogram in the ROOT terminal I am able to get a histogram. It is just when I write it in its own script I am not able to call the branches.
Below is my code:

```cpp
#include "Math/Vector4Dfwd.h"
#include "ROOT/RDF/RInterface.hxx"
#include "ROOT/RDataFrame.hxx"
#include "ROOT/RVec.hxx"
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TH1D.h"
#include "TLatex.h"
#include "TLegend.h"
#include "TStyle.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace ROOT::VecOps;
const auto z_mass = 91.2;

void selectMuon() {
  ROOT::EnableImplicitMT();
  ROOT::RDataFrame df("Delphes;4", "tag_1_delphes_events.root");

  TH1F *histDiMuonMass = new TH1F(
      "mass", "M_{inv}(Z[3]Z[5]); M_inv (GeV/c^2); Events", 50, 0.0, 1500);
  RVec<float> Muon_PT;
  RVec<float> Muon_Eta;
  RVec<float> Muon_Phi;
  RVec<int> Muon_Charge;

  // auto idx_cmb = Combinations(Muon_PT, 2);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < Muon_Charge.size(); i++) {
    if (Muon_Charge[1] != Muon_Charge[2]) {
      ROOT::Math::PtEtaPhiMVector m1((Muon_PT)[1], (Muon_Eta)[1], (Muon_Phi)[1],
                                     0.1);
      ROOT::Math::PtEtaPhiMVector m2((Muon_PT)[2], (Muon_Eta)[2], (Muon_Phi)[2],
                                     0.1);

      auto mass = (m1 + m2).M();
      histDiMuonMass->Fill(mass);
      auto df_mass = df.Define("Dimuon_mass", InvariantMass<float>,
                               {"Muon_PT", "Muon_Eta", "Muon_Phi", "m"});
      // Make histogram of dimuon mass spectrum
      auto h = df_mass.Histo1D({"Dimuon_mass", "Dimuon_mass", 30000, 0.25, 300},
                               "Dimuon_mass");
    }

  } // end of event for loop
  histDiMuonMass->Draw();
}
```

Why isn't accessing the Branch Variables Muon_PT, etc. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please read [example].

Comment: If you don't want to reproduce the error in a form more digestible to a volunteer, consider debugging your code. If you don't know how to use your debugger, now is a VERY GOOD TIME to learn how.

Comment: Hopefully, this is more readible. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: As long as it still reproduces the error, this is a GREAT edit. Thank you.

Comment: It does, hopefully I can find out why.

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't appear to do anything with `i`? It just compares `Muon_Charge[1]` to `Muon_Charge[2]` over and over. Certainly that's not intended?

Comment: Yes, that is true. When I want to add the indices by uncommenting the auto idx_cmb line and adding const auto i1 = idx_cmb[0][i];
      const auto i2 = idx_cmb[1][i];
      if (charge[i1] != charge[i2]) {
         ROOT::Math::PtEtaPhiMVector m1(Muon_PT[i1], etc That is where I get the error that I can't make a unique combinations

Comment: What happens if you explicitly call `histDiMuonMass->Fill(mass);` with KNOWN, CONSTANT masses between 0 and 1500? To see if the issue is with `TH1F` or with your logic that calculates mass.

Comment: Wait, in this example of yours, all of your `RVec`s appear to be empty. There's nothing in them?

Comment: Ok, so when I fill my histogram with a random distribution, I still get an empty histogram. Why are my RVecs empty. How can I call the values from my respective branches into my RVecs? That is, how can I fill my RVecs with values from my Muon_PT branch, Muon_Eta branch, etc

Comment: What is a branch?

Comment: If I write in my ROOT terminal,  auto h = df.Histo1D("Muon_PT") I can get a histogram

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208890/discussion-between-usernew-and-john).